# Number of hours instead of frequency count in a chi-squared test

Tags: survival, chi-squared-test, poisson-regression

I have a sample where subjects dedicate a variable **number of hours** to an activity. During these hours, an event might happen. I have a contingency table such as

```
        Event happened    No event happened
Male              2000             30000000
Female            3400             43000000
```

I want to know, in this example, if an event is as likely to occur to either Males or Females, for every hour worked.

The unit is number of hours dedicated to a task. Because the number of hours a subject worked is variable, I cannot simply use raw frequency of subjects in each group. Would a chi-squared test be suitable, and if not, what are my options?

*Events can happen more than once by subject, but I chose to not take that into account, so I could fit the data to this contingency table. Happy to hear suggestions on how to include it.*

Comment: I think your situation might be more like [survival analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis). More specifically, if you take the multiple events per subject into account, this could be a *repeated events* SA.

Comment: @gung I assume the event is not a function of time since start, but total time must be taken into account to normalise the counts. An event could happen any time, but the longer a subject is working, the longer it is exposed to a potential event.

Comment: Is the event column "exactly one event" or "at least one event"? (It looks to me like a suitable analysis might include the time exposed in either a bernoulli or Poisson model, for which my question there is relevant)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow your comment, @dmvianna. It's not that SA assumes the passage of time *causes* events to occur. Eg, it could be that your survival times would be exponentially distributed in your situation.

Comment: @Glen_b, "at least one event".

Comment: Do you have information on how many events for each case, or is that level of information lost?

Comment: @gung, I am not familiar with survival analysis, hence my comment. Thanks for clarifying this. Still, how would I normalise the fact that some subjects have very long hours worked, and some have very short ones?

Comment: I agree with @gung 's comment a lot. It is a case of survival analysis. If you have an subject, that you followed for 100hrs without seeing the 'event', it can be treated as a right-censored. If you have an obs. for which the 'event' time is observed at 99 hours, then it is a exact time-event. If you have multiple events observed for one subject, it becomes a repeated event or Recurrent event survival analysis. You can have a subjects tracked for only 10 hours (without seeing an event), then it is right censored at 10hrs. You can have subjects that were tracked for different amount of time.

Comment: @Glen_b I have all information and more. How many, how serious, how far into a session...

Comment: In which case, it seems to me a Poisson GLM with Sex as a dummy and hours as an exposure would be an obvious starting point.

Comment: To clarify: in that case (the above Poisson GLM), the number of events is the response, and the idea would be to find the size of the coefficient of Sex (and possibly, test if it differs from zero); it measures the difference in *rate* of events (per hour or whatever other unit you set up the data with) between the two sexes.

Comment: @Glen_b, my data has very few subjects with one event, even fewer with two events and a tiny portion with >=3. I'm unsure survival analysis will detect a difference. Poisson GLM sounds like an excellent tool for a case where the frequency of responses is higher. I'm planning to just consider the first event and drop the rest for a simple survival analysis.

Comment: Poisson GLM should work perfectly well in this situation, but if you really want to turn it dichotomous, you can use binomial GLM on that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the individual data, I would use a Poisson regression model (a kind of glm). Response is number of times event occurred for that individual, (log of) number of hours could be used as an offset. Then sex would be a predictor variable.

See also useful ideas in the comments.